# Is there an efficient way of clustering labelled similar datapoints?

Tags: python, pandas, search, cluster-analysis

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
| Image | Similar Images |
| ------| -------------- |
| 1     | [1, 2, 6]      |
| 2     | [2, 1, 6]      |
| 3     | [3, 4]         |
| 4     | [4, 3]         |
| 5     | [5]            |
| 6     | [6, 1, 2]      |
```

And I want to make clusters of similar images and label them.
What I aim to do would look something like this:

```
| Image | Similar Images | Label |
| ------| -------------- |-------|
| 1     | [1, 2, 6]      | 1     |
| 2     | [2, 1, 6]      | 1     |
| 3     | [3, 4]         | 2     |
| 4     | [4, 3]         | 2     |
| 5     | [5]            | 3     |
| 6     | [6, 1, 2]      | 1     |
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? I have limited computing resources and around 178000 images, which is why I'm wondering if there are any efficient existing methods or packages that could perform (part of) this task.

Answer (score 7):

Try `frozenset` then `factorize`

```
df['new'] = df['Similar Images'].map(frozenset).factorize()[0]+1
```

Comment: Thanks! This was (almost) exactly what I was looking for. I forgot to mention in the post that I am dealing with a lot of transitive relations that aren't always fully annotated (for this example, say image '6' has similar images '6, 1') and that seems so to go wrong sometimes, but nonetheless, I am very satisfied with your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist to use incremental integers for the labels，you can just sort the Similar Images list and calculate its hash, and use that hash for the labels

```py
from hashlib import sha1

images = [
  [1, 2, 6],
  [2, 1, 6],
  [3, 4],
  [4, 3], 
  [5],
  [6, 1, 2]
]

labels = [sha1(str(sorted(item)).encode()).hexdigest() for item in images]

print(labels)

#['c43178906089cf513e06bd8e70af5323c44aeac9',
# 'c43178906089cf513e06bd8e70af5323c44aeac9',
# '848eeae1a32f2e1c3da6f07361b19f7b35913dfd',
# '848eeae1a32f2e1c3da6f07361b19f7b35913dfd',
# '10ae24979c5028fa873651bca338152dc0484245',
# 'c43178906089cf513e06bd8e70af5323c44aeac9']
```

Comment: Interesting approach! I would have never come up with this, thanks!